# my url is url(r'^login/(?P<email>\w+@\w+\.\w+)$', 'login'), how can I get the url as /login

Tags: django, url, parameters

well, if my request path is `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/user/edit/10`, then I want to check whether the current user A has the permission to access the `/admin/user/edit`, when I use `url = request.path`, I get the url as `/admin/user/edit/10`.

But I want to get `url = '/admin/user/edit'` instead `url = '/admin/user/edit/10'`.So how can I get the correct url??much appreciate!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the `permission_required` decorator above your view?

```
@permission_required('app.edit_right') # Fill in your permission    
def edit_user(request):
    #do stuff here
```

If the user (or the groups he's in) doesn't have this permission, then he will be redirected. Look for more info on the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator)